# R gsub a single double quotation mark

Tags: regex, r, escaping, gsub

I have a field of strings in a data frame all similar to:

```
"Young Adult – 8-9""
```

where the inner single `"` is what I want to replace with nothing to get:

```
"Young Adult - 8-9"
```

How can I do this? I tried to escape with a double backslash:

```
gsub("\\"", "", string)
```

but got this error: `Error: unexpected string constant in "gsub("\\"", ""`

Comment: Is `string` created as `string <- '"Young Adult – 8-9""'` or `string <- 'Young Adult – 8-9"'`?

Comment: you need one more backslash (for your code to run - whether it'll do what you want is another question)

Comment: One fewer backslashes works too. Or just `'"'`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You do not need to escape a double quote in a regular expression. Just use `"\""` or `'"'` to match a single double quote.

```
s = "Young Adult – 8-9\""
s
[1] "Young Adult – 8-9\""
gsub("\"", "", s)
[1] "Young Adult – 8-9"
gsub('"', "", s)
[1] "Young Adult – 8-9"
```

See [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/cp4PpW)

NOTE: Since you want to remove some *literal* text, you do not even need a regex, use `fixed=TRUE` argument to speed up the operation:

```
gsub('"', "", s, fixed=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you save a `gsub` with `“”` in a `.R script` file, `“”` is saved as `"`.

```
gsub("[“”]", "", s) # Doesn't work when you save this piece of code in a script
```

The get-around solution is normalizing the double quotation marks first

```
x <- proustr::pr_normalize_punc(your_data_frame, your_column_name) %>%
     mutate(your_column_name = gsub('\"','', your_column_name))
```

You can guess that `proustr::pr_normalize_punc` converts all `“”` to `\"`