# Replace an object within a string and avoid quotation

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have an object `A`. I would like to have `'10'` which is not in quotation anymore: `10` (similarly like `1000` and `5000` in object `A`). The following example gives me `'10'` instead of `10`.

```
A <- " 'value_1':1000, 'value_2':5000, 'value_3':'10' "
gsub('10', 10, A)
```

Comment: `gsub("'10'", "10", A, fixed=TRUE)` - no need escaping and regex mode is redundant here

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew you're right ; i'll edit my answer. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R gsub a single double quotation mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282579/r-gsub-a-single-double-quotation-mark)

Comment: That's a quite similar question but honestly, I would keep mine as well since implementing the solution you gave into my issue might not be that straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
A <- " 'value_1':1000, 'value_2':5000, 'value_3':'10' "
gsub("'10'", "10", A, fixed=TRUE)
```